# How do I make my cheese "crackers" less greasy?

Tags: cheese, low-carb

To provide my diabetic guests with a low-carb option for dipping, I make cheddar cheese "crackers" by melting small mounds of cheddar on a silpat at 400° F. Once the cheese has started to bubble very slowly, I remove them, dab them with a towel to remove excess grease, and then place them on paper towels or brown paper, flipping them once, to cool and wick away additional grease. Not surprisingly, the crackers are always very greasy even with the dabbing/wicking.

What could I add to the shredded cheese to make the crackers less greasy without dramatically increasing their carbohydrate count, and how much of that ingredient should I use (assuming two cups of cheddar per "recipe")? In lieu of adding anything to the cheddar, is there an ingredient with which I could dust the crackers to help cut down their greasiness without dramatically increasing their carbohydrate count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real cheese crackers are always going to be a little greasy. You can reduce this by using a lower fat cheese like mozzarella.

I think you'd benefit by adding some flour to absorb some of the oil. Try starting with a 1/4 to 1/3 ratio of flour to cheese. From what I understand, whole wheat, whole grain, and oat flour are much more friendly to diabetics. You could even try something exotic like mesquite or yellow pea flour.

Answer (score 4):

I'd first try experimenting with different cheeses; different brands or ages of cheese may behave differently.  You can also try hard cheeses, as I've made something similar with hard grating cheeses (parmesean, pecorino romana).

Also, how you buy your cheese may be significant; many packaged pre-shredded cheeses contain cornstarch to reduce clumping, which might help to reduce the 'greasiness' of the final item (although adding carbs).